# Why is my network share access different across machines?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, network-share, file-sharing

**The Issue**

I recently moved a few file shares to a new server. The file shares kept the same name, permissions, and contents.

I then changed the group policy mappings in active directory to point to the new file shares.  After that was finished, I disabled the old file shares.

I then started logging into a few machines I use and noticed that on most of them (9/12) everything worked perfectly.  After a `gpupdate /force` The new shares appeared, and functioned as expected.  However, on three of my servers, I now have no access to these shares.  I'm using the same account across all 12 machines, but on 3 of them, when I open the new share, I have an escalation of privilege dialogue open, and ask for an admin account (which is strange b/c I am logged in as an admin, and the other machines don't ask me to escalate).

**What I've tried**

- Clearing any type of cache I can think of
- Restarting
- Ensuring that all machines I'm using are all pointing to the same AD server
- Adding new users to the access group.
- I noticed that the 3 machines that couldn't access the share were all 2008r2's, but I also have 2008r2 servers that can access everything correctly.

**Clarifications**

The new file share server had old shares on it, and they are all still working as expected.  Only the new shares, that moved from the old server are acting abnormally (3/12ths of the time).

I would have more guesses on what could be wrong, if it weren't working anywhere, but the fact that it's broken only on 3/12ths of the machines I've used has me stumped.

Comment: 'I am logged in as an admin' -- AD admin or local admin on the server?

Comment: I have tried both, but I have been trying consistently with AD admin.